# Why can I read the registry key values but not write it the same way?

Tags: powershell, registry

To harden windows I want to disable netbios on all computers. With the following powershell script I can easily read all Network Adapters Netbios setting.

```
$RegKeys = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces'
$RegKeys | ForEach-Object {
  $_.GetValue("NetbiosOptions")
}
```

This works great so I thought analog to this I can change the settings like this:

```
$RegKeys = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces'
$RegKeys | ForEach-Object {
$_.SetValue("NetbiosOptions", 2)
}
```

But it says it can't be written into the registry key. So why is the reading working and not the writting? Of course I run both with admin rights.

If I do it this way it is possible:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces\Tcpip_{Example}" -Name NetbiosOptions -Value 2
```

Comment: You can not write key if it open only for reading. You need to reopen it for writing.

Comment: thank you for your answer but how could i reopen it for writing?

Comment: `.OpenSubKey('', $true)`